# Continue even in case of the error in javascript

Tags: javascript

There are 2 scripts on the page. If the first one causes an error, then the second refuse to work because of this.

How do I make the second script turn a blind eye to the first one's errors and work anyway? Keep in mind that I'm **not** allowed to change the first script.

Comment: Show your problematic code and errors. Separate scripts shouldn't have any problems with each other unless second tries to use data that were supposed to be initialized in first.

Comment: won't a simple try/catch solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this might help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stoperror()
    {
        return true;
    }
    window.onerror=stoperror();
</script>
```

MOZILLA DEVELOPER NETWORK [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.onerror)

Answer (score 2):

I would use try and catch blocks, and disregard any error.

That should work..

Example

```
try
{
    //Run some code here
}
catch(err)
{
    //Handle errors here
}
```

Comment: Right! (+1)... If there is an error and exception is not thrown, that would mean you have syntax error

Comment: Not necessarily syntax error. Any error that is not a thrown exception will still be an error. E.g. `somevar.somefunc()` if somevar is `undefined`, `null`, etc.. `catch` will only be entered if `throw` was issued during execution.

Comment: in any case, whether your `catch` block gets fired or not, `try` will avoid script from crashing

Answer (score 2):

Javascript execution stops when the error occurs...

You can not change this behavior...

To get around, put the code that causes an error inside `try` block

```
try{
    //code that might produce some error
} catch(e){
}
```